# iMacros 10.3 Determine if a button is grayed out

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, imacros, peoplesoft, vba

I'm working on macro (Excel VBA) that will loop through a series of vouchers in PeopleSoft Accounts Payable.  After the macro "saves" the voucher, it will click on the "Next in List" button.  This works fine.

The vendor has over 5,000 vouchers.  In PeopleSoft AP, only 300 records can be displayed at a time.

What I want to do is validate the "Next in List" button to see if it is grayed out (and not available).  If it is grayed out, then I will perform some other action to display the next 300 records.

Is this possible?  Can iMacros determine if a button is "available" or not?

I'm using iMacros 10.3 and PeopleSoft Accounts Payable 9.1 and Internet Explorer 11.

Thanks for the help.....

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I know of, if Yes is present it will click it, otherwise it will click No.

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:Yes
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:No
```